# How to join three table to see all the rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

(domains)

```
+----+-----+
| id |title|
+----+-----+
| 1  | com |
+----+-----+
| 2  | net |
+----+-----+
```

(slabs)

```
+----+-----+
| id |title|
+----+-----+
| 1  |str1 |
+----+-----+
| 2  |str2 |
+----+-----+
```

(prices)

```
+----+------+--------+
| id |slabid|domainId|
+----+------+--------+
empty
```

here is my query:

```
SELECT
  prices.*, 
FROM
  prices 
  RIGHT JOIN domains ON domains.id=prices.domainId
  JOIN slabs ON slabs.id=prices.slabId
```

how should I get query to list by domains & slabs rows...

and the result should be like this:

```
+----+------+--------+
| id |slabid|domainId|
+----+------+--------+
| 1  |1     |1       |
+----+------+--------+
| 2  |2     |1       |
+----+------+--------+
| 3  |1     |2       |
+----+------+--------+
| 4  |2     |2       |
+----+------+--------+
```

but it didn't.

Comment: are you on sql server or mysql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `INNER JOIN` will suffice your needs. If one of the fields on table `prices` is *nullable* and you want to display all records on the table whether it has a matching row on the other table or not, use `LEFT JOIN`.

The `INNER JOIN` will only display the record if it has atleast one match on each table. While `LEFT JOIN`, on the other hand, will display all row on the *left hand side* whether it has a match or nonmatch on the other tables.

```
SELECT  a.*,
        b.title domainTitle,
        c.title slabsTitle
FROM    prices a
        INNER JOIN domain b
            ON a.domainID = b.id
        INNER JOIN slab c
            ON a.slabID = c.ID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

**UPDATE 1**

You need to use `CROSS JOIN` for this because you need the product of the two tables, assuming that you want to insert it on table `prices` and `ID` is *Identity* or `AUTO_INCREMENTed` column,

```
INSERT INTO prices (slabid, domainid)
SELECT  b.ID as slabID, a.ID as domanID
FROM    domains a
        CROSS JOIN slabs b
```

If the column `ID` on table prices is not auto_incremented and you are using `mysql`, use a variable to hold an increment the value,

```
SELECT  @ID:=@ID+1 ID,
        b.ID as slabID, 
        a.ID as domanID
FROM    domains a
        CROSS JOIN slabs b
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @ID:=0) s
```

Comment: I really like the visual representation of the sql joins provided in your link!

Comment: and the result row counts should be (slabs rowcount * domain rowcount)

Comment: oh you haven't mentioned that on your problem. but hey, can you give sample records with your desired result so we can work it out?

Answer (score 0):

Just cross join *DOMAINS* with *SLABS* table. Not sure why PRICES table plays a role here, since you just want to permutate the rows in DOMAINS table with the rows in SLABS table.